# Lotto Number Generator

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to create a lottery number generator that does specific things in order.

1. Generate `index1` of 5 numbers between 1 and 69
2. Generate `index2` by adding a 6th number between 1 and 26 to index1
3. Generate `index3` from `index2`, resulting in all possible combinations but keeping the 6th space a random number between 1 and 26
4. Print `index3` with spaces instead of commas

At the end of the first phase listed above, I want to generate a list of every possible number combination for the lottery, keeping the first 5 colums separate from the 6th but all on the same line.. I just started coding last night and havent been to sleep yet. This idea is still evolving but Im stuck. Here is the code that I have come up with so far..

```
import itertools
f= open('index3.txt','w')
numb = range(1,69)
numb1 = range(1,26)
it = itertools.combinations(numb,5)
for x in it:
    f.write(str(x))
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

I can get a random list of all numbers but I cant seem to get them and keep a seperate 6th colum that will have only the numbers between 1 and 26

Answer (score 0):

You've already done `index1`. To do the next ones, you'll need to

- Run through `numb2` to combine it `y` with `x`
- Turn it into a string and change the commas to spaces
- Remove the space at the end of each entry

I've added comments and the code which should help you.

```py
import itertools
f= open('index3.txt','w')
numb = range(1,69)
numb1 = range(1,26)
it = itertools.combinations(numb,5)
for x in it:
    for y in numb1: # to run through index2
        six = list(x)
        six.append(y) # add index2 to the set of numbers
        final = ""
        for item in six:
            final += str(item) + " " # add spaces to it
        final = ''.join(final[:-1]) # remove space at end
        f.write(final)
        f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response.. I will research how the new info that you gave me works to gain a better understanding. Question: It seems like nothing will happen until index1 is finished printing and then it will start to build index 2. Is there a way to load all of this information in memory instead of printing it, have it run all of the functions and then just print out the end result in index3?

Comment: I feel like the issue is with..                                                      
         it = itertools.combinations(numb,5)                                                Im just not sure how to defiine it to add numb1...

Comment: ? It combines everything when writing. @TimothyK. I used a nested for loop. Essentially, for every item in `it`, it'll go through `numb1`. Essentially, `numb1` is your `index2`. Then, I combine it to create `final` which is `index3`. Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but the script is only generating 5 colums of numbers instead of adding the sixth one, to form index3.. I ran the script until it finished and got a 5gb file but each line only had 5 colums. Below is the first few lines that get generated..

Comment: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: It remains like that, (just in rows not colums) for 25 lines and then the last digit becomes a 6.

Comment: Ah, wups. You just need to replace `f.write(str(x))` with `f.write(str(final))`. I am so sorry! @TimothyK.